# Serialize HashSet of enum variants as a regular HashMap using rocket serde

Tags: rust, serde, rust-rocket

```rs
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
enum En {
    A(i32),
    B(String)
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Data {
    data: Mutex<HashSet<En>>
}
```

When using this structure, serializing the struct outputs something like `{"data": [{"A": 0}, {"B": "String"}]}`, I'd like to remove the list from the json and combine the data into one map (`{"data": {"A": 0, "B": "String"}}`).

I'd like to keep the HashSet for unique data and to force each variant's type, is there a way to do that without having to implement my own serialize or deserialize methods.

I've tried using serde_as from the serde_with crate with the `as` type `Mutex<HashMap<String, _>>`, though I keep getting errors saying "the trait bound `HashMap<Same, Same>: SerializeAs<HashSet<En>>` is not satisfied"

I have a partial solution using a HashMap instead of a HashSet, though I'd prefer if it was possible to keep using a set.

Comment: Please give an example of the JSON output you desire.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a separate enum with just the variants `A` and `B`, no data, which you can use as the keys of the hashmap.

Comment: @PitaJ I edited the post to include an example of wanted output

Comment: @BallpointBen do you mean with serde_as? I'm still getting the error with as = "Mutex<HashMap<Name, En>>"

Comment: What should happen if you have two `En::A`‘s in the set?

Comment: The old one should be replaced, though I guess that can be done with just Eq implementation

Comment: Something similar is possible using the `EnumMap` type from `serde_with`. https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/struct.EnumMap.html It does not work with `HashSet`, but only with `Vec<Enum>`. You receive the "trait bound" error message, because you cannot just write anything in the `serde_as` attribute. Specific combinations are allowed: https://docs.rs/serde_with/2.2.0/serde_with/guide/serde_as_transformations/index.html

Comment: @jonasbb This appears to be working, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the serde_with crate seems to work

```rs
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Data {
    #[serde_as(as = "serde_with::EnumMap")
    data: Mutex<Vec<En>>
}
```

As a replacement for a HashSet I used the strum crate AsRefStr trait, implemented PartialEq and Eq using it and used Vec.retain() when I inserted data